# Not getting correct value in return

Tags: php, mysql

The idea of the task is to allow the user to add and withdraw "money" to and from their account. The problem is I can add money, but I can't withdraw it

```
$funds = $_POST['funds'];
$withdraw_or_add = $_POST['list'];

if($withdraw_or_add == "add")  
{
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$funds."' WHERE userId = 1";
}   
else  
{
  $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = '1'");
  $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);
  $new_fund = $info['userFunds'] - $funds;
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$new_fund."' WHERE userId = 1";  
}


mysql_select_db('details_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```

So for example, let's say `$fund = 5` and `$info['userFunds'] = 20` then the variable `$new_fund` should be `15`. But instead it equals `-5`. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! ***SQL Injection!*** *It's not just for breakfast any more!*

Comment: You need to connect to your db first before you can query and where is `$conn` defined along with the form for this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The $conn is above this code and the form is below. I believe it is all correct.

Comment: Sounds like your variables or math is off. Try `echo "$new_fund = {$info['userFunds']} - $funds;";` after your math line to make sure the data and math looks like it should.

Comment: Check value of $_POST['list']. Most probably you are getting true for your first if condition (if($withdraw_or_add == "add") )

Comment: First of all 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$funds."' WHERE userId = 1";
doesn't add anyhthing, but simply sets a value.
Also I would check the input and make sure you are using the right column types. I suppose you should use floats. So floatval($info['userFunds']) and don't store $new_fund as a string in your SQL query.

Comment: according to what you put in here, everything looks good. there must be something behind the scenes.  examine the variables in this line `$new_fund = $info['userFunds'] - $funds;` , echo them and see, are they as expected or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly page of top you put used db connection related code :

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('details_db');
```

and then bellow and removed `mysql_select_db('details_db');` line after `mysql_`

```
$funds = $_POST['funds'];
$withdraw_or_add = $_POST['list'];

if($withdraw_or_add == "add")  
{
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$funds."' WHERE userId = 1";
}   
else  
{
  $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = '1'");
  $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);
  $new_fund = $info['userFunds'] - $funds;
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$new_fund."' WHERE userId = 1";  
}


//mysql_select_db('details_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Updated data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```

Note: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. `mysql_*` [extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Please used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).